# Cascade Thuderbolt (tb) 3 to tb2 daisychain and to USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, external-disk, thunderbolt, drobo

Have following setup. Macbook Pro (mbp) with two thunderbolt ports. A Drobo thunderbolt 2 disk with daisychain ability (two ports) and now need to connect USB-C portable disk. mbp connects to Drobo via Apple tb3->tb2 connector and tb2 cable. When I plug tb2 cable to Drobo's second port with tb2->tb3 connector to USB-C port nothing happens.

All this since need to copy a massive volume, need power supply, but mbp has only two ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple TB3-to-TB2 adapter only does conversion for the Thunderbolt protocol and nothing else, it will not pass through USB or DisplayPort.  USB-C will allow for a number of protocols, including Thunderbolt, USB, DisplayPort, and perhaps more.  USB-C is a specification for a physical connector, a specification that does not require support for the USB protocol.  There's two parts to USB, the physical connection and the protocol, and having one does not necessitate support for the other.  Just because the TB3-to-TB2 adapter has a USB-C physical connection does not mean it supports the USB protocol.

What I found that works for me is a Thunderbolt USB-C dock.  Connect the dock by a Thunderbolt cable and each USB-C port will support Thunderbolt and USB 3.x.  This works because the dock contains a controller chip for USB.  If the dock is connected to the host by a passive USB-C to USB-C cable then it should support DisplayPort in addition to ThunderBolt and USB.

A USB (that is USB the protocol, not just the physical connection) dock will not support Thunderbolt devices.  Thunderbolt is a variation on the PCI protocol and so it is cheap and easy to add a USB controller, PCI is how USB controllers are connected to the computer CPU internally.  There's no adapter to get Thunderbolt devices to talk the USB protocol, but there are adapters for USB devices to connect to Thunderbolt.

I'm assuming the USB-C drive you refer to is using the USB 3.x protocol as it is not functional with a TB adapter.  If it is a TB drive then the problem may be a lack of power.  While TB ports will provide something like 10 watts of power there may not be a whole lot of power left after chaining two TB adapters together.  A powered dock or hub should resolve that issue.

As I see it the solution is a Thunderbolt dock or hub regardless of where the issue lies.  If there is not enough power to the drive then you need something in the middle to provide power.  If the issue is trying to connect a USB protocol device to a Thunderbolt port then you need something in the middle to do the translation.  A Thunderbolt hub or dock will provide both power and USB controller.